# OnChange on Input not working after vite build

Tags: reactjs, vite

I am having issues where the onChange method stops working after I build my React project with Vite. It works fine on the dev server but after I build the project it stops working.

I also have a Select element that works fine with onChange.

```
const [filterText, setFilterText] = useState('')

useEffect(() => {
   console.log(filterText)
},[filterText])

return (
   <input type="text" value={filterText} onChange={(e) => setFilterText(e.target.value)} />
)
```

The input element changes the value on the input element on dev mode but after I build with `vite build` it stops working. The value attribute on the input element is not changing when typing in the input field. And as mentioned I have a select element with the onChange method that is working just fine.

This is my vite config:

```
export default defineConfig({
  base: './',
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {
    manifest: true,
    rollupOptions: {
      input: '/src/main.jsx',
      output: {
        entryFileNames: `assets/main.js`,
        chunkFileNames: `assets/main_chunk.js`,
        assetFileNames: `assets/main.css`
      }
    },
  }
})
```

Comment: Do you see any console errors when trying to change the value?

Comment: @sneakysquid Nope, 0 console errors occur

Comment: @elmgren I [cannot reproduce that](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-nxdnqn?file=src%2FApp.jsx). Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?

Comment: @tony19 I found the problem. I implemented my app on a website which had GA scripts:

```
<script>
 window.ga = function() {
  ga.q.push(arguments)
 };
 ga.q = [];
 ga.l = +new Date;
 ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
 ga('send', 'pageview')
</script>
<script src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js" async defer></script>
```

When I comment out this section, it all works just fine. Why? I have no idea. And at this time I don't have the urge to troubleshoot it :)

(Note I had to comment out both scripts for it to work, wouldn't work with just one of them)

Comment: That might be helpful to someone if you post it as answer, explaining exactly the conditions that cause the problem.